# Permission denied when executing mvn from inside docker container of official maven image

Tags: linux, docker, maven

I'm trying to build my code inside a container, so I created a Dockerfile from maven official images and tried to execute maven inside that container, but bash is throwing "Permission denied" when running the mvn command.

I've then tried to isolate the problem and created a very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven
RUN mvn --version
```

When I execute this simple Dockerfile, it throws the error on line 2: `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/mvn: Permission denied`.

So, I've tried to investigate the mvn command permissions inside the container, with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven
RUN ls -la /usr/bin/mvn
RUN ls -la /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
RUN id ${whoami}
RUN mvn --version
```

The results:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.36MB
Step 1/5 : FROM maven
 ---> 8ebd3d89902a
Step 2/5 : RUN ls -la /usr/bin/mvn
 ---> Running in fcd887d9aacf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 May 22 02:13 /usr/bin/mvn -> /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
Removing intermediate container fcd887d9aacf
 ---> bfd60797390b
Step 3/5 : RUN ls -la /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
 ---> Running in 1c7c7f237444
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5741 Nov  7  2019 /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
Removing intermediate container 1c7c7f237444
 ---> e3351b0ed7c8
Step 4/5 : RUN id ${whoami}
 ---> Running in 7a4db16f1831
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Removing intermediate container 7a4db16f1831
 ---> fe875f847f70
Step 5/5 : RUN mvn --version
 ---> Running in 0c5eb52d25d9
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/mvn: Permission denied
Removing intermediate container 0c5eb52d25d9
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn --version' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

Everything seems to be fine: running as root user, files are all owned to root...
I'm building it with the command:

```
docker build --rm --no-cache -t testdocker:latest .
```

I've tried running it as `sudo` with the same results, unfortunately.

I'm running with a user with uid=1000, using ubuntu 18.04. Funny thing is it worked for a while, but then it stopped (probably after I've messed with something I shouldn't lol).

Does anybody here have any ideas on how to tackle this situation?

Comment: Why not using the offical docker images?

Comment: I spun up an ec2 instance on AWS and ran exactly what you have above. It seems to be working. Can you reproduce on another machine?

Comment: The scenario is working fine within my ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance (Docker version 19.03.8). Maybe you need try something else, like 1, check free disk space. 2, fix the maven image tag (instead of default `latest`).

Comment: @khmarbaise, that image is an official one.

Comment: @AustinPoole, another person in my office is having the exact same problem, with the same environment as I have.

Comment: @Dai, there is enough disk space, and I've tried with different images.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not on the image (or Dockerfile), but rather on my environment, since the same Dockerfile **was** working at some point. Probably something I've installed or messed up with and shouldn't. The key thing is finding out **what**. lol

Since this other person in my team have the same problem that I do, it's possible that some customization we've made to our environment for our project has created this whole situation.

I'll try to spun a new machine and create the development environment again, to see if I can find the exact point when things went sour.